# Story where (deceased? frozen?) people are used as means of propulsion

Tags: story-identification, generation-ship, propulsion

I recall a story (or perhaps the memory is from a book?) where a spaceship accelerated by jettisoning human bodies at high speeds. I suppose they did not have any other reaction mass left. I think it was an ark ship using frozen bodies after making that heart-wrenching decision.

I think an approaching observer only realized what the trailing "string of pearls" was when they got close enough.

The story or novel is probably relatively recent (post-2000).

Comment: I also recall it, but it seems to have been the decision to *jettison* cryopods with "probably not revivable" people that reduced the payload mass of the ship. The other ships in the convoy did retain those almost-corpses and thus arrived later at the new colony.

Comment: Yeah, vaguely familiar to me as well but I can't think of any names. IIRC there were several colonising sleeper ships all doing basically a 'land rush' to a newly opened planet . Unscrupulous captain and crew do the unthinkable and jettison all the cryo people to ensure they get there first . When the other colony ships arrive the bad guys have already staked a claim to the prime lands and resources

Comment: "Chasm City" by Alastair Reynolds has some generation ships racing to a planet, and one gets an advantage by jettisoning cryopods.

Comment: I immediately thought of Chasm City, but it has no mention of the jettisoned bodies being used as reaction mass or of them looking like  string of pearls in space.

Comment: Yes "Chasm City" doesn't fit the original question very well, but it seems relevant to the comments of o.m. and DannyMcG.

Comment: @ClaraDiazSanchez e.a.: Hm. I'll take a look t it. Maybe it was in one of Dozois's Year's Best?

Comment: This also made me immediately think of Chasm City. Anyone feel like posting it as an answer? Happy to do it myself but credit should really go to Clara or John if it's right...

Answer (score 5):

As I mentioned in the comments, when I read this question I (and some others) immediately thought of "Chasm City" by Alastair Reynolds. Some aspects do not fit well with the original question however, notably that in Chasm City the bodies were ejected to reduce the mass of the ship and assist its *deceleration*, while the question dealt with bodies being ejected to cause *acceleration*.

Reynolds wrote a short story entitled "[Night Passage](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?2249821)", also set in the Revelation Space universe, which has many features similar to the section described in Chasm City, but seems a better fit. In this story, a sleeper ship gets trapped midway through its interstellar trip by an unexplained phenomenon. The engines are put out of action, and so to escape they jettison cryopods (or "reefersleep caskets" as they are called) using a magnetic launcher. The caskets are visible from the ship, not quite as a "string of pearls" in the original question, but as "brief, bright scintillations":

> The flashes continued. Now that I was attuned to their rhythm, I
> picked up an almost subliminal nudge in the fabric of the ship,
> happening at about the same frequency... Each nudge was the cargo
> launcher firing another casket away, the ship's motion reducing by a
> tiny value. It produced a negligibly small effect. But put several
> thousand negligibly small effects together and they can add up to
> something useful.

This was published in "[The Year's Best Science Fiction: 35th Annual Collection](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?666911)" edited by Gardner Dozois, which may accord with one of the OP's comments.

Comment: That's Reynolds levels of dark.

Comment: Technically speaking acceleration is just a change in velocity, and deceleration is a qualifier for acceleration opposite the direction of travel. Also, since motion in space is relative, each body jettisoned would technically by traveling slower than the previous in one direction or faster than the previous in the other. Without the perspective of direction of travel, someone might mistake it as accelerating away instead of decelerating towards...